# Java arraylist outofbounds

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I know that this question has been asked a million times. And I feel like the solution will be fairly obvious to someone who hasn't been staring at it for a couple of hours. But I can't make head or tails of my out of bound exception. Here is the error:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 207493, Size: 207493
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at affysureselect.AffySureSelect.main(AffySureSelect.java:92)
Java Result: 1
```

I was thinking perhaps this might be happening due to the size of the arraylist, but if that were the case I would have expected the error to be when adding, rather than the getting. Here is the code where it is dying:

```
    String chrompos;
    ArrayList<String> chromnum = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((input2 = sbuff.readLine()) != null) {
        prse = input2.split("\t");
        chromnum.add(prse[0]);
        ...
        chrompos = prse[7];
     }
    int cnt = 0;
    int cnt2 = 0;
    if (chromnum.get(cnt).equals(chrompos)) { // line causing my untimely death
      end = Integer.parseInt(chromposend.get(cnt2));
      start = Integer.parseInt(chromposstart.get(cnt2));
       ...
```

I even tried adding:

```
if (cnt <= chromnum.size()) { //this line
  if (chromnum.get(cnt).equals(chrompos)) { /before the dying line
```

But it dies anyway, on the get, not the add. What am I missing?

Comment: `System.out.println` the list, and you'll see you have less elements than you think

Comment: The problem is that you're confusing 0-based indexing with 1-based indexing. If your list has 10 elements, the indexes that the elements exist at are `0-9` (when you just use `ArrayList.add( Object)`. Your check to make sure an index exists in the `ArrayList` would be `if (cnt < chromnum.size())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are incrementing cnt, make sure that it's always less that chromnum.size().

It should be-

```
if (cnt < chromnum.size())
```

Comment: Oh. Duh. I knew it would be a really silly thing. Thanks so much. I will accept in 11 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Index i does not exist. You must always iterate to `list.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the index `i` if the size of the `ArrayList` is also `i`. The maximum accessible index is `i-1`. Hence, the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which says you're trying to access the `207493`th index, even when the size of your `List` is also `207493`.

Have a check to restrict `cnt` below the size of your `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as per the code it looks like, that in **if** loop you are trying a

```
 chromnum.get(cnt) and cnt is initialized to 0.
```

So the most probable issue is that the code never entered the while-loop, juts put a SOP after the while loop and check for the arraylist size.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equal sign,

```
if (cnt < chromnum.size()) { //this line
      if (chromnum.get(cnt).equals(chrompos)) {
```

Hope to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that lists start with 0, so if you have a list of N items the last item will be N - 1 (because 0 is the 1st element, 1 is the 2nd and so on)

So you should write

```
if (cnt < chromnum.size()) {
```

instead of

```
if (cnt <= chromnum.size()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

1-based like Pascal: United States, English-speaking Canada.
0-based like C/Java: Quebec, (most of?) Europe.

That's the answer. The question is, How are floors indexed in an elevator.